# How to reindex a dataframe specifying center

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,1,1,1], index=pd.date_range('1/1/2013',periods=4))
print df
            0
2013-01-01  1
2013-01-02  1
2013-01-03  1
2013-01-04  1
```

How do I reindex the DataFrame by specifying the 0 index and let it auto fill the rest of the indices? For example, if I specify the index of the last item to be 0, then I should have the following:

```
    0
-3  1
-2  1
-1  1
 0  1
```

**Edit**

Instead of specifying the row number, I want to specify the target date for the 0 index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work?  I'm assuming you're discarding your current index and switching to integer indices.

```
In [132]: df = pd.DataFrame([1,1,1,1], index=pd.date_range('1/1/2013',periods=4))

In [133]: target_zero_row = df.index.get_loc('2013-01-04')

In [134]: df.index = pd.np.arange(df.shape[0]) - target_zero_row

In [135]: df
Out[135]: 
    0
-3  1
-2  1
-1  1
 0  1

[4 rows x 1 columns]
```

You could achieve the same thing this way, too:

```
In [180]: df = pd.DataFrame([1,1,1,1], index=pd.date_range('1/1/2013',periods=4))

In [181]: target_zero_row = df.index.get_loc('2013-01-04')

In [182]: df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

In [183]: df.index = df.index + (-target_zero_row)

In [184]: df
Out[184]: 
    0
-3  1
-2  1
-1  1
 0  1

[4 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @acowlikeoject. I updated my question, how would you go about solving my new requirement?

Comment: @zsljulius Does that work?  Added another method, which shows that you're really just discarding the index and adding/subtracting as necessary to reindex at 0 at your desired row.